# What is the difference between an electron in ground state and an electron in excited state?

Tags: spectroscopy

What is the differnce between a ground state electron and an excited state electron? Upon excitation what exactly changes about the electron?

Comment: What makes you think there's a difference?

Comment: *Bohr* was the man! *Just* a matter of orbital change on absorption and emmision.....

Comment: Could you explain what your understand of a ground state and an excited state is?

Answer (score 5):

You can think of electron states as book shelves and electron as a book. Is there anything different about that book if it stands on lower or upper shell? Not really. Same is with electron in different states.

I guess what made you think otherwise is the fact that electron in lower electronic states has a lower potential energy. When electron occupies higher(excited) electronic states it has more energy, and by releasing it in a form of photon it may be relaxed to lower(ground) electronic state. So the difference is in amounts of energy electrons in different states have.

Also, since electrons in different electronic states are described by different wavefunctions, probability density will be different. And other observables, besides energy, will have different values.

Comment: thancu for u r elaborate explanation